# SQuirreL SQL client does not show Json data

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, squirrel-sql

I just have a Postgres database(PostgreSQL 9.4.5) and Squirrel windows client (SQuirreL SQL Client Version 3.7).

In database there is a table which has column type jsonb

```
 Column | Type
--------+-------
 id     | uuid
 jddd   | jsonb
```

when I do

```
select jddd from request;
```

I see

```
<other>
```

in the results area. When I do the same in psql command line client I see JSON data which are there. I tired to google it but I found no posts related to this topic at all.

This was promising https://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/1139/ but did not help neither:-(

Thanks in advance,

st.

Comment: You can probably workaround that bug by casting the jsonb column to json or text: `select jddd::text from request;` or `select jddd::json from request;`

Comment: Great! It helped, thanx a lot.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pls post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 40):

Under the following two sections:

1. Global Preferences > Data Type Controls > SQL Other (SQL type 1111)
2. Global Preferences > Data Type Controls > Unknown DataTypes (non-standard SQL type codes)

you should check the checkboxes saying

`[X] Read contents when table is first loaded and display as string`

as shown in the below image:

[image: Snapshot for reference]

Comment: As of SQuirrel SQL 20170430_2224
Global Preferences > Data Type Controls > SQL Other (SQL type 1111)
Global Preferences > Data Type Controls > Unknown DataTypes (non-standard SQL type codes)

Comment: Actually it is:
File > Global Preferences > Data Type Controls > SQL Other (SQL type 1111) Global Preferences > Data Type Controls > ...
(At least for beginners ;))